# Getting probailities for two events

Tags: probability, problem-solving

When producing something while having a chance of 4% for getting a bad item I can calculate the chances for having 2 bad items by just using the Bernoulli formula

$$
P(x=k) = ( \begin{matrix} n \\ k \end{matrix} ) \times p^k \times (1-p)^{n-k}
$$
(in the parantheses n is over k)

So if I enter my values (took 50 items for testing, having $4%$ chance of bad item, want to have the chances of having 2 bad items):
$$
P(x=2) = ( \begin{matrix} 50 \\ 2 \end{matrix} ) \times 0.04^2 \times (1-0.04)^{50-2}
$$
I get as result a chance of $27.62%$.

But another task is to calculate what is the probability that "at least 3 items are bad.

For this I looked for some binomial distribution calculator (at least I think they are called this way) and came to a solution that just takes the chances of having 1 bad item as q1 and 2 bad items as $q2$, sum them up and subtracts that $(q1+q2)$ from 1 (so instead of summing up all the chances of having $3, 4, 5, ...., 50$ bad items, I take the whole chance and just take away the chances of having 1 and 2 bad items.

But the solution seems wrong. Can someone tell me where my mistake is?

Using symbolab.com and summing up the chances 
$$
\sum _{x=1}^{50}\left(\frac{50!}{x!\cdot \left(50-x\right)!}\right)\cdot 0.04^x\cdot \left(1-0.04\right)^{50-x}
$$
tells me that the `Input is invalid for sequence calculations`

Thanks!

Comment: Well, your method omits the possibility that there might be $0$ bad items.  I don't know why your software rejected that summation (which, again, should start at $x=0$ if you want to get $1$).  Perhaps it dislikes "$x$" as a discrete variable?

Comment: you seem right. when just summing up from $x$=0 to 2 and applying it to the coefficient, the parser throws the same exception (input invalid). But how can I avoid this or what is the correct way?

Comment: As I say, I don't see anything semantically incorrect about your sum.  Of course, I don't know the software you mentioned, neither do I know what code you typed for it.  I expect there is a coding error.  Check term by term.  Can it evaluate the summand for $x=0$ or $x=1$?

Comment: In MathJax, you can use `${n\choose k}$` for ${n\choose k}$

Comment: the software I'm using is https://www.symbolab.com. Its a online parser like wolfram alpha

Comment: Ok asked in a different way: If I have n guesses, I want exectly k elements to fit my condition, I use the first formular. But when at least k elements have to fit my condition is this the right way to subtract the sum of the chances from 0 to k-1 from 1?

Comment: Well, it is a correct way.  In this case it is clearly better than the direct sum, since the sum of three terms is a lot easier than the sum of $48$ terms.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you use software, you can simply use CDF of binomial; with R:

```
> 1 - pbinom(2,50,0.04)
[1] 0.323286
```

Or if you prefer to use PMF instead of CDF

```
> x <- 0
> for(i in (3:50)) x <- x + dbinom(i,50,0.04)
> x
[1] 0.323286
```

or else

```
> x <- 0
> for(i in (0:2)) x <- x + dbinom(i,50,0.04)
> 1-x
[1] 0.323286
```